# Dual boot repair after a reinstall

Tags: partitioning, ssd, multi-boot

I have (had) a dual boot desktop with W7 and W8. I installed a new SSD, and after days of failed attempts at cloning using several different software options, I gave up. So I did a clean install of W7. I still have the intact W8 system on the original drive (but if W8 has it's own boot partition, that's gone.) 
Anyway to salvage this? I don't even remember how I added the W8 system in the first place. I think I did it from an iso file. It's a legal copy, but my wife got it for her authoring gig somehow and I don't think I have a way to reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

The utility ["Dual-boot Repair"](http://www.boyans.net/dual-boot-repair-tool-for-windows-8.1-update.html) can run on Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8, 8.1
and has an option "Automatic Repair".

What it does is to place the correct boot files for the latest Windows OS on

first disk either active partition (for MBR disks) or ESP (EFI System Partition for GPT disks).

In your case where you have two disks they must be either both MBR style
or both GPT style so you can boot them using Windows boot manager (from first disk) and a dual boot menu.

If you have two disk, one MBR and one GPT, dual-boot is only possible by selecting boot device
from firmware using "one time boot device selection key" (F10, F11, F12 depending on computer brand).

1. First check that every disk is bootable by selecting it from firmware.
2. Install Dual-boot Repair tool on either system/disk. Run it, click "Automatic Repair".
   This will make computer to boot by default to latest OS (Windows 8 in your case).
3. Reboot. In Win8 install [Visual BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net). Run it.
   Select "Create missing Windows loaders" or just type F9-key - this will create a dual-boot entry for Windows 7 in your case.

That would be all.